# What exactly is voltage in this case?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, voltage

My textbook states the following:

> Voltage is the same across each component of the parallel circuit.

However I am confused on what the exact meaning of voltage is in this case, is voltage used interchangeably for potential difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the potential difference *is* the voltage.